# Cannot unmount unconnected transport endpoint because of chdir failure

Tags: permissions, fuse, overlayfs

I try to unmount an unconnected endpoint (created by `mount.posixovl`), but when I try to unmount the endpoint using `fusermount -u` I get a `failed to chdir`.

```
» fusermount -zu ./overlaydir
fusermount: failed to chdir to /home/nfs/hwalinga/mounts: Permission denied
```

I tried `-u` and `-zu`

Answer (score 0):

All directories in the path leading up to the mount point need to be executable. I my case my home folder was not executable.

```
chmod +x /home/nfs/hwalinga
```

This solves it.